# Difference between <> and != operators in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators

I was working in MSSQL server 2012. I wrote a query

```
select * from Mytable where col1 is not null and  col1 != ''
```

and

```
select * from Mytable where col1 is not null and  col1 <> ''
```

Both returns same value. I am just curious to know, what is the actual difference between `<>` and `!=` operators?

Comment: Thanks. I searched the question in stackoverflow and I could not get it. So I posted this question. But this question is duplicated:-)

Comment: They're both not equal, which is to say they're equivalent to each other...  Here are handy alternatives too:  `WHERE NULLIF(col1,'') IS NOT NULL`  or `WHERE ISNULL(col1,'') <> ''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!=` is not ANSI compliant.
That's all.
Use `<>`

UPD. Oh, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that there is no difference. The `<>` operator is the ANSI SQL standard inequality operator, while Microsoft included `!=` to make it like some programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is no difference between != and <>. Both of them work the same way and there is absolutely no difference in terms of performance or result.